# What's the easiest way to get the next sibling (wrapping) on a canvas in WPF?

Tags: wpf, collections, wpf-controls, children

We have a canvas that has a Children collection with an indexer.  We have a reference to one of the children.  We just want to get the next child in the list, and if we go past the end, we want to wrap around again.

We're currently doing this via looping to get the index of the one we have, then we increment that, check the bounds and wrap if necessary, then use that result to get the child from the indexer...

...but that just feels so three-lefts-to-go-right to me.  I have to be missing something.

Note: If there's a generic solution for any index-based collection, that would be great, but even if it's just canvas-specific, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be missing something, but I think what you want could be easily achieved, say I have some XAML like this

```
<Canvas x:Name="canv">
    <Rectangle x:Name="canvChild1"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="canvChild2"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="canvChild3"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="canvChild4"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then all you need is to grab a safe index (ie one that wraps), so assuming I have a handle to the 1st element, and want to grab next, and then 4th and wants to grab next, I could use code like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Debug.WriteLine(GetSafeElementForIndex(
            this.canv.Children.IndexOf(canvChild1)).Name);

        Debug.WriteLine(GetSafeElementForIndex(
            this.canv.Children.IndexOf(canvChild4)).Name);
    }


    private FrameworkElement GetSafeElementForIndex(int currentIndex)
    {
        return (FrameworkElement)this.canv.Children[WrappedIndex(++currentIndex)];
    }


    private int WrappedIndex(int currentIndex)
    {
        return currentIndex % this.canv.Children.Count;
    }
}
```

This prints this:

canvChild2

canvChild1

I think you could also use Colin Eberhardts excellent LINQ to Tree stuff, which would allow you to use LINQ against the Visual Tree : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62397/LINQ-to-Tree-A-Generic-Technique-for-Querying-Tree

That is pretty handy stuff, that allows you to treat the VisualTree as you would XML, and navigate different axis.

Comment: Aaaah!  Things I didn't know for $200, Alex!  The 'IndexOf'!  I knew I was missing something simple.  I can use that in a Linq query (or even better, an extension method) to give me exactly what I wanted. (That eliminates my need for the looping-lookup.)  The vote is yours (...and welcome to StackOverflow!  I'm sure your score will go up quickly.)

Comment: BTW, one suggestion: When posting code, you can eliminate the 'usings' up top and the class itself.  You only need the relevant methods.  Also, try to remove double-blank lines. All of those things make for unnecessary scrolling both horizontally and vertically.  Still, great code example.  Simple and clear!

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be using a canvas directly, but rather an `ItemsControl` with a canvas as `ItemsPanel`. You could also use a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) on top of the items this allows you to get and move a `CurrentItem` around (`MoveCurrentTo*`).

Comment: Hmmm.  Interesting food for thought, but not applicable to my question.  I mean what does ItemsControl give you to solve my question about getting the next item in a collection?

Comment: @MarqueIV: The `ItemsControl` is a bit of an aside, you probably do not need it to work with `CollectionViews`, but it might be a good to have this separation between the collection and the `Canvas`.